# Building an array in nested foreach loops in Laravel controller

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to build an array of user ids from a long eloquent relationship, using nested foreach loops in a Laravel controller, but can't get it to work.

Users can have publishers, those publishers can have teams and each team has members. Users can be in multiple teams so I also need to remove duplicate IDs.

I want to end up with a count to see how many team members are associated with a user.

In my user model

```
public function publishers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Publisher')->withTimestamps();
}
```

In my publisher model

```
public function teams()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and in my team model

```
public function members()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('status', 'title', 'team_role_ids')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and in my profile controller

```
foreach ($user->publishers as $userPublisher) {
  foreach ($userPublisher->teams as $publisherTeam) {
    $teamUserIds[] = $publisherTeam->members->pluck('id')->toarray();
  }
}
$deDupedIds = array_unique($teamUserIds, SORT_NUMERIC);
$idsCount = count($deDupedIds);
```

But I'm getting multiple arrays and not just one compiled array and the count isn't working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding arrays of id `$publisherTeam->members->pluck('id')->toarray();` as a new index in `$teamUserIds` . but what you want to do is to `merge` the array of ids

so your code would be like this :

```
foreach ($user->publishers as $userPublisher) {
  foreach ($userPublisher->teams as $publisherTeam) {
    $teamUserIds = array_merge($teamUserIds , $publisherTeam->members->pluck('id')->toarray());
  }
}
$deDupedIds = array_unique($teamUserIds, SORT_NUMERIC);
$idsCount = count($deDupedIds);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a new array into `$teamUserIds` each iteration. That's why you are getting multiple arrays.

```
$teamUserIds = [];
foreach ($user->publishers as $userPublisher) {
  foreach ($userPublisher->teams as $publisherTeam) {
    $teamUserIds = array_merge($teamUserIds, $publisherTeam->members->pluck('id')->toarray());
  }
}
$deDupedIds = array_unique($teamUserIds, SORT_NUMERIC);
$idsCount = count($deDupedIds);
```